# How can I tell which one is the name if the object has more than one CN attribute?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I'm trying to show a simple list of domain groups that the user is member of. I'm querying the AD to find out about a user's group. To my undestanding, the CN is the "unique name" of the object, relative to his parent.

```
"CN=Internet,OU=Groups,DC=elver,DC=do",   
"CN=Developer,OU=Groups,DC=elver,DC=do",
"CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=elver,DC=do"
```

Now look at the third group. It has two CN attributes. How should I interpret that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my undestanding, the CN is the "unique name" of the object,
>   relative to his parent

NO. Actually, CN stands for `common name`. You're confusing with CN because CN is usually the RDN (explained in the answer below) in frequently used examples. In Active Drectory, CN applies to all but a few object types.

There is this concept called [`Relative Distinguished Name (RDN)`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977992.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is actually the name used to uniquely reference an object within its parent container in the directory. It is actually an attribute of the object — the part of the object name that identifies the object as unique from its siblings at its current level in the naming hierarchy.

1. when DN = "CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=elver,DC=do", the RDN of the object is "CN=Remote Desktop Users", which is unique in the Builtin Container.
2. when DN = "CN=Developer,OU=Groups,DC=elver,DC=do", the RDN of the object is "CN=Developer", which is unique in the parent container Groups.
3. when DN = "CN=Internet,OU=Groups,DC=elver,DC=do", the RDN of the object is "CN=Internet", which is again unique in the parent container Groups.

> How can I tell which one is the name if the object has more than one
>   CN attribute?

So, I believe you know the answer now. The leftmost CN in the DN would be the actual common name for the object which would be unique too, inside the container marked ahead in the DN.

---

```
NOTE: The term "container" refers to one of two things:
      (i) An object of the container structural class.
      (ii)An object that has child objects.
```

Answer (score 1):

CN is the 'common name' of an object in ldap, DN is the 'distinguished name' of an object in ldap which is globally unique.

In your example, in AD, "builtin" is a container (vs an OU) which is denoted in "CN=" in the string. Its perfectly legal to have something like "CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=elver,DC=do" which refers to a single object.

Long story short, each of those strings is an DistinguishedName with the *FIRST* (farthest to the left) CN= being the Common Name.

Comment: so "CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=elver,DC=do" would be the DN and "CN=Remote Desktop Users" is the CN?